# Variable value replaced with another value

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js

```
yMax = 100;
this.dataBoundaries = {

        x: function () {
            var lastCol = that.extractLastColumn();
            return [d3.min(lastCol), d3.max(lastCol)];
        },
        y: [
            0, 100
        ]
    };
console.log(this.dataBoundaries);
```

The above code will result to print y with another values instead of [0,100] => [0,34.....], Why this happen?

Comment: can you elaborate the problem? because this.dataBoundaries not print the value of y, it will give the properties name(x and y) not there value.

Comment: I feel there is code missing from your post

Comment: Please, provide more code. If you execute this, you'll get the object with two properties and it will have y as [0, 100] exactly as you defined above. This will change only if you execute another code before the console.